# Does Help, Pix! grant kills to the recipient of the buff or Lulu?

Tags: league-of-legends

Lulu can cast Help, Pix! on allies and enemies. If she casts it on an ally, Pix's magic missile barrage attack triggers on the ally's auto attacks. If an enemy is killed as a result of this damage (rather than the triggering auto attack) is Lulu granted the kill or is her ally granted the kill?

Comment: I hope they didn't make a support champ with a built-in kill-stealing move...

Comment: I would guess that the buffed champion gets the kill, but in the case of Karmas shield I believe Karma gets the kill, so anything is possible.

Comment: I can't comment on whether or not it does, but I have a feeling that LuLu could potentially snag a kill since Pix is doing the damage. Instead of infusing the AD carry with extra damage, Pix is now the one doing the damage...which could grab the kill.

This question begs to know if Pix becomes the carrie's ally, like Pix is LuLu's ally, or if the are two separate entities.

Comment: @Emerica Well, with Karma's shield, it's a damage nuke she's casting out from the target, not as if it was a damage return or DoT effect supporting the target.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [this](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1928198) thread the kill is awarded to the Ally buffed. It works the same as Leonas passive. I have seen a few LuLu games and also the answer in question in that thread has +10 so one can infer they are correct.

Answer (score 2):

There was a Riot post that states the Ally Buffed gets the kill, I have however experienced a situation where I buffed the jungler and they were after a buff that I got (I was not actively doing any damage).  We assume pix got the final hit and the buff itself transferred to me instead of the jungler so beware of that possible hiccup in your travels :)

Comment: Please, can you post the link of this post too ?? will help other users as well

Comment: Was linked by the other poster: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1928198
Wanted to mention the apparent buff glitch (unless I missed something like a dot but I dont think I had anything that did one at the time) and not steal their answers thunder :)